# Spyder stop running when screen s blocked

Tags: python, ide, spyder

I am using python spyder to develop some of my tools. After starting my tools with spyder, it works perfectly, but when I block my screen, spyder stop running my code and only return it after I unlock the screen.

I am using Spyder 4.2.0, ANACONDA 1.10.0 and UBUNTU 18.04.

PS.:This issue happened also in Older versions of ANACONDA and UBUNTU

Comment: can't you run code without `spyder` ? If you have working code then you don't need editor/IDE to run it.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please open a terminal and start Spyder with the following command: `spyder --debug-info verbose`. Then block your screen, unblock it and see what error messages are reported there.